# Strange javascript equality issue

Tags: javascript

I have the following conditional in a node js app. Even though console is tracing out 'r' I am NOT getting past the if statement. Can anyone suggest what might be happening?

```
console.log('content.toString()' + content.toString());

        if (content.toString() == "r") {
```

Here is the complete method...I'm wondering if its a scoping issue?

```
dGramSocket.on('message', function (content, rinfo) {
    console.log('got message from', rinfo.address, rinfo.port);
    console.log('sockIO.sockets is ' + sockIO.sockets);
    console.log('content.toString() BEFORE trim ' + content.toString());
    var dir = content.toString().trim();
        if (dir == "r") {
            //CODE DOESN'T REACH HERE!!
            console.log('content.toString() AFTER TRIM' + content.toString());
        }
   // }
});
```

Comment: Maybe there are spaces? Log the string length as well as the value. Is the `if` statement *really* right after the `console.log()` or is there more code you haven't posted?

Comment: Well if the string really contained `"r"` the `if` statement test would work. If your `console.log()` call really is the statement just preceding the `if` then the situation doesn't make a lot of sense. What is the value of `content`? What sort of object is it, in other words, and what does its `.toString()` method do?

Comment: added complete method, see above. I see the 'content.toString() BEFORE trim' but not AFTER

Comment: What is the value of `content` before you do the `toString.trime()`

Comment: what is dir.length ?

Comment: Just as an experiment I might try `if (/^r/.test(dir))` (and maybe without the `^` if that doesn't work ...)

Comment: value of content before trim is either l or r. And typeof is object. BUT dir.length AFTER trim is still 2, so something weird is happening.

Comment: Pointy- that regex did the trick. But what exactly is it doing? Add as an answer and I will approve. Even after trim is it possible there is still some hidden special character-line return??

Comment: if dir.length = 2 so there is an invisible char, what is the result of dir.charCodeAt(1) ?

Comment: this regex is testing if the string begin with r, this could not be a line return because trim() remove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `if (content.toString().trim() == "r")`

Comment: doesn't seem to make a diference...I wonder if I should be supplying an argument to toString()...

Comment: what does it output if you do console.log(typeof content); ?

Comment: And the output for  console.log(content); ?